# CrudRepository save method not do an update

Tags: mongodb, spring-data

I am trying to do an upsert using the CrudRepository `save()` method

```
testRepository.save(myObject);
```

it turns out that the update not take place but throw the below exception:

```
com.mongodb.DuplicateKeyException: Write failed with error code 11000 and error message 'E11000 duplicate key error collection: db.collection index: _id_ dup key: { : ObjectId('5b3bc303a162ef3e28fc861e') }'
at com.mongodb.operation.BaseWriteOperation.convertBulkWriteException(BaseWriteOperation.java:243) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.4.1.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.operation.BaseWriteOperation.access$300(BaseWriteOperation.java:60) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.4.1.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.operation.BaseWriteOperation$1.call(BaseWriteOperation.java:144) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.4.1.jar:na]
```

Do I miss anything? I am using MongoDB 3.6.3 and mongo-java-driver-3.4.1

Comment: check your  ObjectId('5b3bc303a162ef3e28fc861e'). ist already exist in your collection.

Comment: you have to remove _id from your myObject.

Comment: or you have to remove old indexing and try again.

Comment: if he removes _id, a new document will be inserted, with new _id. BUT the old one will remain the same, and not be updated!!!

Comment: yes, I tried to do an upinsert, so if the _id exists in the document, it should update the document in the database instead of throw this exception. I don't want to insert a new one